# Unit test - best practice for a multilayer project

Tags: unit-testing, project

I have a project with different layers of abstraction, which can be splitted in the groups:

- **Internal API;**

  - Data Access Layer (DAL)
  - Business Access Layer (BAL)
  - ...
- **Public API**

  - Public accessible classes that have access to the internal data;
  - REST endpointes.
  - ...

And inside Public API services I use Internal APIs.

1. Is it required to write Unit tests for all this layers or only for Internal API?
2. Are there any best practices?
3. Should I start writing my tests from Internal API and move to the next layer bottom-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would say is "Yes." In other words, test everything.

For the internal API, you can write true unit tests with mock objects for the DAL and each class tested in isolation. This isn't just good to test for verification sake but also to give you confidence your code works and to serve as documentation of the code. That confidence comes in handy too when, for example, a REST API call fails later and you need to narrow down where the problem is.

You can test your DAL with an in-memory database for speed. I would call that an integration test while others would call that a unit test. Just semantics. But you got to do that too.

The Internal API tests are by developers for developers.

The testers should help with anything public facing. You simply write integration tests for the API services and REST client tests to verify the common cases and the obvious exceptional cases.

It sounds like a lot, and it kind of is. But if you take the time to get to know your tools and set up automation everywhere you can, you will be amazed how much you can accomplish pretty fast.

Hope this helps.